# Multithreaded Server C++, Socket Programming

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, server, epoll

I am learning socket programming. I have built a client server program, where each client is handled by an individual thread in server program. But after a certain number of threads the system's performance will degrade.
Now, to solve this, my task is to make my server handle multiple clients (say N connections) with a single thread, and only create a thread when there are more than N connections, and manage those N connections.

Say, 1 thread currently can deal with 200 clients, I will create another thread, when 201th connection arrives.

How to achieve this? And what is the proper way to manage those N connections?

Here is my code:

Client Code

```
#define PORT 9876

bool client(struct sockaddr_in* server_addr, int& socketDesc)
{
    memset(server_addr, (char)0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (socketDesc < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open socket" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    server_addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server_addr->sin_port = htons(PORT);

    int n;
    if ((n = connect(socketDesc, (struct sockaddr*)server_addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) < 0))
    {
        cerr << "Connect Failed" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    return success;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    
    int socketDesc;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    
    client(&server_addr, socketDesc) > 0)
    
    const char* hello = "Hello from Client Side";
    

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << hello << endl;
        send(sd, hello, strlen(hello), 0);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Server Code:

```
#define PORT 9876

void server(struct sockaddr_in* server_addr, int& socketDesc)
{
    memset(server_addr, (char)0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    
    socketDesc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (socketDesc < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open socket" << endl;
        return;
    }
    server_addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr->sin_port = htons(PORT);
    int n;

    if ((n = bind(socketDesc, (struct sockaddr*)server_addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in))) < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot Bind" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if ((n = listen(socketDesc, SOMAXCONN) < 0))
    {
        cerr << "Cannot Listen!" << endl;
        return;
    }
}
void func(struct sockaddr_in* client_addr, int& new_sd)
{
    char memory[1024] = { 0 };
    int n;

    while ((n = recv(new_sd, memory, 1024, 0)))
    {
        cout << "Current Thread ID " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
        cout << buffer << endl;
    }
    
}
    
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int socketDesc;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server(&server_addr, socketDesc);

    vector<std::thread> poolofthread;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t length = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    int new_sd;

            
    while ((new_sd = accept(socketDesc, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, (socklen_t*)&length)) > 0)
    {
        cout << "Client Accepted" << endl;
        thread t(func, &client_addr, ref(new_sd));
        poolofthread.push_back(move(t));
    }
    return 0;

}
```

This Code for each client handled by separate thread is working fine.

I have tried handling each client with a single thread.
Now, I want to handle N connections with a single thread. And only create a new thread when it is necessary(LIKE, when more than N connection arrives).

If you can give some idea about the best way to manage those N connections, then it would be helpful. I am learning select(), poll and epoll.
How can I use them and which will be best with my case and why?

I have tried clearing the question and the problem I am facing. If you don't understand any part please write in the comments.

Comment: Well you seem to have some knowledge of *thread pools*. I suggest you begin by abstracting the pools into classes and objects. Then add functionality to add a new connection to the pool, and then let the pool decide which existing thread should handle the connection or if a new thread might need to be created. The threads themselves are also abstracted out so it's easy to create and add connections to it. You should probably take some time to learn more about *object oriented programming* and classes and abstraction.

Comment: Thanks, actually i have a very little idea about thread pool. Will it solve my problem?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just mentioning as he looks new, and he have another question for you

Comment: @zenitsu7 The way you describe it, it seems like you need a kind of [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). Perhaps not a straight up standard thread pool, as the threads in such a pool typically does one thing at a time. Your threads need to handle multiple connections each.

Comment: I read about thread pool, it seems we are creating a certain number of threads in the beginning itself, and making use of those threads, as our new task comes in. But is there a way, of only creating a thread when needed?? Rather then in the beginning itself. Because there might be a case, when the the number of threads created in the beginning might be too large, if task is very low. And too small, if task number is large.

Comment: A thread pool could create a number of threads beforehand, *or* create new ones on demand. But remember that thread creation and destruction could be quite expensive, so if you know approximately how many you might need, it makes sense to create around that many to begin with, and when threads are no longer needed then let them linger on a while to make sure they're not needed again soon. I also recommend you spread the work (the connections) evenly between the treads instead of letting a single thread get "full" before using the next thread.

Comment: Thanks, I just created the threadpool and yes, it solved my problem.

Comment: Just for fun, I recommend checking out my toy project exactly on this theme. It features an event-loop + thread pool design to implement all sorts of async applications: https://github.com/barbu110/micro.

Comment: Can you handle multiple connections without creating additional threads? Managing that (probably using `select()`) should be your next step. You can build your multithreaded server mased on that and then serve N connections per thread. That said, your question remains unclear. No clear problem, no error messages, no concrete and verifiable goals. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also note that you can and should [edit] your question to clarify it, so people don't have to collect different pieces from comments.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichEckhardt for you suggestion. I am new here, so I asked what was on my mind. And yes, now my next step is managing them. I checked, there are three ways to manage them, select, poll, epoll. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `select()` is widely available anywhere I know. `poll()` seems to be from POSIX, so probably Linux and Unix systems (incl. MacOS X). `epoll()` and `ppoll()` are Linux-specific. Under Windows, I'd consider `WaitForMultipleObjects()`. Use `select()`, it's portable and you can easily find examples.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest you to read some about different server architectures and design methods.
I had the same problem as yours and found this amazing [website](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/concurrent-servers-part-1-introduction/) that explains different types and architectures of servers along with their pros and cons and challenges. Pay attention that it has multiple parts. It'll start with beginning to design a server and at each step improves it.

For a short description, a good practice design is that there's a `netIOManager` (could be a `ThreadPool`) that will only receive net data and hand it over to a `MainManager`(also another `ThreadPool`) to process that data and then immediately return to its main job which is receiving net data.

The `MainManager` may have further database tasks(also another `ThreadPool`) and then after processing the data it will deliver the response to the `netIoManager` so it will send the response to the client.
[here's a visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It9gT.png)

As you can see in this scenario you have 3 `ThreadPool`s(services) that can be connected using **task Queues** between them(see [producer consumer problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-problem-in-c/#:%7E:text=The%20producer%2Dconsumer%20problem%20is,the%20buffer%2C%20and%20start%20again.))

If you search the internet there are many implementations of thread pool for C++.

Also for `netIOManager` part again i recommend you to read that site i mentioned earlier. The event-driven solution is the best i have found so far

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Thread Pool.
Creating a thread pool in a way, that it launches a new thread, only at a certain condition.
It solved my issue.

Comment: Sharing a code snipped could improve the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).